# Is it possible to do an OSD image over displaycameras

Tags: omxplayer

I found a video on how to use displaycameras to show rtsp feeds of my companies camera system but they now want a Logo on the bottom center of the screen. Is it possible to do an OSD over the camera feeds using omxplayer?

Comment: This is a few years old but may help https://www.codedesigner.de/articles/omxplayer-kivy-overlay/index.html

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try.